# JavaScript: Trying to use a variable from a page loaded inside a DIV in another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I'm trying to use a variable from a page loaded inside a DIV in another DIV.

The text in the "bar" DIV on the "index.html" page should be replaced by the item id selected from the "page.html" loaded as an `<object></object>` inside the "content" DIV.

Or the item id should at least be stored in a global variable - which hasn't been working either - because when I run a function from the "index.html" page to retrieve it, it displays as "undefined".

All the code is below:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css">
    <title>Access element of other DIV</title>  
</head>

<body>  

    <div id="bar">This text should be replaced by the Item ID selected below</div>

    <div id="content">

        <object type="text/html" data="page.html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**index_style.css**

```
body{
margin: 0px;font-family:arial;font-size:30px;text-align:center;color:#fff;
}

#bar{
position:relative;height:100px;line-height:100px;background-color:#555c60;color:#74de90;
}

#content{
position:absolute;top:100px;bottom:0px;right:0;left:0;overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

**page.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page_style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

<center>
This is <b>page.html</b> which has been loaded <u>inside</u> the "content" DIV<br><br>
</center>

<div class="items" onclick="use_item_id(this);" id="item1">Item 1</div>

<div class="items" onclick="use_item_id(this);" id="item2">Item 2</div>

<div class="items" onclick="use_item_id(this);" id="item3">Item 3</div>
```

**page_style.css**

```
body{font-family:arial;font-size:30px;color:#fff;background-color:#1b1e4b;text-align:center;}
.items{cursor:pointer;}
.items:hover{color:#ff0000;}
```

**main.js**

```
function use_item_id(selected)
{
current_item = selected.getAttribute("id");
document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = current_item;
alert(current_item);
}
```

The line `document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = current_item;` in "main.js" seems to be the problem and I can't get it to work. The `alert(current_item);` works fine when the line above it isn't there so it's definitely getting the item id's correctly from "page.html". It's just not setting them as the `innerHTML` on the "index.html" page, or even storing them in a global variable to be retrieved from a function run on the "index.html" page (as mentioned above). Any code examples would be greatly appreciated.

I think it might be because the `use_item_id()` function is being executed from another page, so I might need some alternatives or other functions to get it to work.

It'd be great if anyone knows what the issue is. I appreciate all replies. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not on the same document ... then in main.js
replace
`document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = current_item;`

with

`parent.document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = current_item;`

this **solves your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access variables from HTML documents it's highly recommended to use the `data attribute`. This is an example for a comment section:

In my item I set the data key for loading

```
<div class='resp-col col-12 comment-user-data'>
    <div class='resp-col col-9'>
    <div class="post-profile-image" style='background-image:url("<?=$user->profile_image?>")'></div>
    <?=Html::a("<p class='post-user'>".$username."</p>", Url::to(['/account/'.$user->id.'/'.$user->username]))?>
</div>
    <div class='resp-col col-3'><button class='reply-to' data-assoc-id='<?=$model->id?>' data-assoc-name='<?=$username?>'><i class="material-icons">reply</i></button></div> <-- set the data-assoc-id
</div>
<div class='resp-col col-12 comment-content-data'>
<?=$model->content?>
</div>
```

jQuery to load data key

```
$('.reply-to').on('click',function(){
    $('#submit-comment').data('assoc-id', $(this).data('assoc-id'));
    $('#comment-content').val('@'+$(this).data('assoc-name')+' ');
    $('.base-modal').animate({
scrollTop: $("#comment-content").offset().top
}, 2000);
if($('#comment-content').css('display') == 'none'){
toggleCommentVisibility();
}
});
```